# Animated Home screen for android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an app and want to add an animated logo to the pre launch screen of the app. Just like Myntra has one for them [myntra launch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix12y.png)
And here is my logo mp4 [my app launch screen](https://i.imgur.com/5pFbXUy.mp4)

Please help me where i need to change the things and how i can add it.

Answer (score 0):

The one that you're looking for is called *Splash screen*.
During cold start, a white screen is shown. Some applications ( if not to say all) use a splash screen to display their logo instead.
There is a Google library for that. check it from here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: how can i add an mp4 as a splash screen?